Near-field-communication [nfc] recomendation
I want to ask a question about NFC, but I don't have enough reputation to create the tag. Can someone create it, or is there a similar tag to this?

Can I confirm: are you asking a game design question about how to use NFC as a game mechanic, or a programming question about how to integrate NFC with game-specific libraries/engines? Those would be on topic here. If you want to ask about what libraries to use to interface with NFC, that would not be on-topic here, nor would a general "how can I write a program to interact with NFC" as that would belong on StackOverflow. Ask on GameDev.StackExchange if there's something unique to games in the answers you need, that would not apply to other NFC software.

I'm going to ask if I can use NFC as a game mechanic. I have a few ways of using NFC, like trading something like Pokèmon or in-game supplies.

"If" you can use it? Who or what are you worried would stop you?

In the way I want to use it, the browser, probably.

That sounds like a question for StackOverflow: "How do I read an NFC tag in the browser". You do not need game-specific expertise to answer that question. A simple search suffices.

Go ahead and ask the question and link it here.
Assuming the question is on topic, and we find the tag will be useful to future questions, we will happily add it.

+1: Tags are not a prerequisite to asking questions on a topic. Once a topic has enough questions about it, we create the tag and add it retroactively. The system will require you to add some tag, but you can use the tag for the programming language you're using, "networking" if you're using NFC to communicate between two players' games, "game-design" if you're asking a question about how to design a mechanic that uses NFC, etc.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/211914/is-there-a-way-to-read-data-from-an-amiibo

I have one more question ready, but I already had another question about NFC and amiibo all ready for me to submit (I actually completely forgot about it).
